# Хорошая архитектура ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, архитектура

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь разобраться в том, как правильнее составлять архитектуру ASP.NET приложения. Я понимаю, что это зачастую очень индивидуальный вопрос, но все же.

Я посмотрел два варианта архитектуры: многоуровневая и Onion.

**1. Многоуровневая.** Изучал [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.5.php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь мне не очень понравился тот факт, что Data Access Layer содержит и модели, и логику их хранения в БД.

**2. Onion архитектура и DDD**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первый взгляд все хорошо, но при приближении к реальности возникают вопросы.

- Говорят, что бизнес-логика должна быть в Domain. Но ведь для ее работы необходимо осуществлять операции с БД, т.е. зависимость от, условно, `IRepository`

**3. Гибрид** Подумав, я пришел к такой гибридной архитектуре:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Я намеренно учел в ней изначально поддержку Identity/другого аналогичного решения, потому что иначе это может стать трудно
- Отдельные интерфейсы для разных репозиториев, потому что Generic-repository -  [антипаттерн](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/) , потому что не позволяет учитывать особенности разных моделей.

### Собственно, вопрос

Как вы считаете, будет ли эта архитектура достаточно удобной в использовании?

#### UPD

User, Role - получается, что Domain Models оказываются зависимы от Identity, чего хотелось бы избежать. Или это нормально и маппить их на DTO в слое бизнес-логики?

Comment: "Здесь мне не очень понравился тот факт, что Data Access Layer содержит и модели, и логику их хранения в БД." - это не так. Туториал по вашей ссылке врет. Модели в стандартной 3-х уровневой архитектуре лежат в BL. Разница между ней и Onion в основном в том, как нарисована диаграмма - кому-то не понравилось что DAL нарисован внизу, он воспринял это как "в основе лежит база" и придумал другую визуализацию того же подхода.

Comment: DDD - это подход, ставящий в основу домен. Совершенно неважно, как при этом нарисована диаграмма слоев. При этом бизнес логика - это неотъемлимая часть домена. По сути - домен это и есть набор сущностей, инкапсулиющих логику предметной области. Т.е. домен == бизнес-логика. Непонятно, как вы смогли разделить их в своей гибридной архитектуре :)

Comment: Сорри за полотно в комментах, но вопрос в его текущем виде - скорее всего оффтопик, т.к. единственный честный ответ на него - "возможно". Если бы была универсальная архитектура, 100% удобная - ее давно бы все приняли и пользовались.

Comment: @PashaPash, я встречал мнение, что бизнес-логика находится в сервисах. Как реализовывать бизнес-логику в домене? Толстые модели? Но модели не могут сами обращаться к базе, это уже какой-то ActiveRecord. В отдельных классах?

Comment: "Модели в стандартной 3-х уровневой архитектуре лежат в BL.". Т.е. DTO?

Comment: DTO - это не модели. это просто объекты для передачи данных. То, что вы подразумеваете под "логикой в сервисах" - это т.н. anemic доменная модель ("ненастоящий DDD"). Модель (сущности) в DDD и не должны обращаться к базе. Это решается через persistence ignorance - например, через Code First/Change Tracking/Lazy Loading в EF. На пальцах получается примерно так - на самом верху ваш "сервис/фасад" создает/загружает из базы (контекста) корневую сущность для операции, дергает в сущности нужный метод, потом сохраняет все изменения (context.SaveChanges). Сами сущности с базой напрямую не работают.